# How to export unity 3d scene to Android Studio

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was working on android project, I needed to use Unity

I tried a very simple scene with a cube and simple UI text object as shown below
[image: simple scene]

I spent a little time searching how to use this scene in Android Studio. I got a lot of tutorials but nothing worked for me.

I tried to export with this settings below:
[image: export settings]
and with this package name `com.peixa.helloworld`

I choose the directory to export this project to and I got this error.

here is the error:
`Invalid build path: c:/users/abdelhamied/desktop/test/location
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`

I was struggling the whole day with this error, spent a lot of time searching but no result.

I did this before but I can't remember how I did it.

BTW: I could successfully build the project to APK file

I use `android sdk tools 26` and `unity 2018.3.0f2`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry about that dumb question 
i tried it again and made new folder and i worked it seems like a bug 
anyway it works now 
sorry for your time